# Custom filter for Primefaces pickList

Tags: primefaces

I am trying to create a custom filter for the picklist of primefaces. When I follow the instruction in the manual I get a TypeError somewhere in primefaces.

My definition of the picklist

```
  <p:pickList id="theId"
    value="#{...}" var="variable"
    itemLabel="#{variable.something} #{variable.somethingelse}" itemValue="#{variable}"
    converter="#{genericConverter}"
    showSourceFilter="true" showTargetFilter="true"
    filterMatchMode="custom" filterFunction="myFunction"></p:pickList>
```

my filterFunction

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
                    function myFunction(itemLabel, filterValue){
                            return  itemLabel.indexOf(filterValue) != -1;
                    }
        </script>
```

When I type something in the searchfield I get this error in the console

```
Uncaught TypeError: Property 'filterMatcher' of object #<d> is not a function
```

It seems that the property filterFunction is passed as a String to the primefaces javascript code so this can't be used as a function.

Any help would be great,
 Thanks
Wim

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug in primefaces.
I've created an issue for it and including a workaround.
https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=6233

Kind regards

Comment: Would it be possible to include the workaround in your answer?